# How to add <li> to your image slider - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im working with slider in CMS. It fits screens height, but I have problem with my images scaling down. Is there any CSS solution that I could add to `img{}` to make it not scale? Or I wonder if there is any javascript solution to add `<li>` to your slider `div > ul` and make it as background and still make it run as normal as if image is coming from CMS itself?

I have this:

```
<div id=imageSlider>
 <ul class="hs_cos_flex-slides-main">
      /* here <li> goes but I would like to place it my self if possible*/
 </ul>
<div>
```

I tried something like this

```
$("#imageSlider ul").append('<li></li>');
```

but don't know exactly how to fix it.

This is javascript run from CMS for slider

```
<script>
window.hsSliderConfig = window.hsSliderConfig || {};
window.hsSliderConfig['module_1489510806896497'] = {
    mode: 'slider',
    mainConfig: {"animationLoop":true,"direction":"horizontal","slideshowSpeed":5000.0,"controlNav":true,"smoothHeight":false,"namespace":"hs_cos_flex-","slideshow":true,"selector":".hs_cos_flex-slides > li","animation":"slide"}
};
</script>
```

Comment: your solution should work so long as you are calling `.append()` AFTER the slider has been generated.

Comment: Most sliders make their own li elements so either refactor that for your needs(time consuming and may break more things)(transform images into li elements that contain and image and some text maybe), either build your own slider when you can control the items generation.

Comment: @AdamCopley, you need to instantiate an empty slider then add the li element with append, even then you can't be sure that the slide doesn't have a MutationObserver to regenerate the slider with the new item.

Comment: Yes probably is easier just to make my own in this case. But was wandering if it can be modified. But thanks guys anyway! :)